# Who exactly is Benjamin Anderson in the Kill la Kill soundtrack?

Tags: music, kill-la-kill

I was listening to the *Kill la Kill* soundtrack which is amazing but I'm scratching my head over this particular artist who contributes vocals, Benjamin Anderson. I tried googling/wiki'ing and I found this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin_Anderson_(musician)) - But I don't think it's the same person...? There doesn't seem to be any mention of *Kill la Kill* on his website.

I would love to find out exactly who it is, just to be sure. I thought the vocals were amazing and would like to see if this person had any previous work?

Comment: Believe he only had a small role in kill la kill, only the suck my blood song. And all he did was some vocal text parts in between.

Comment: @Dimitrimx But he also did the vocals for "I want to know" and was credited for it. It's really nice.

Comment: Then as off now those are his only works within anime. He does have a some other songs. But hey, you already know that. As those are listed on the wiki ^^

Comment: @Dimitrimx You mean the url I posted...? I can't tell if it's the same guy though. The OST isn't listed on there.

Comment: Its the same guy. Wikipedia gets filled in by the community. And no community member has edited his profile since: 16:33, 13 November 2013‎ JustAGal. So in the end, you pretty much answered your own question. With your own question.

Comment: @Dimitrimx How do you know that the Benjamin Anderson in the Wikipedia article is the same one that sung for KLK?

Comment: @senshin. Go listen to some of his works. You will hear. Thats how i confirmed it

Comment: @Dimitrimx Sure, that works. If you've listened to some of the works by the Benjamin Anderson on Wikipedia and determined that they sound similar enough to the Benjamin Anderson on the KLK soundtrack to claim that they're the same person, that'd make for a fine answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Wikipedia article you linked to is **NOT** the same Benjamin Anderson who worked on the Kill la Kill soundtrack. They were born in different countries, in different years, and have absolutely nothing else in common.

The correct Benjamin Anderson was born in London, UK and currently resides in Japan.

- **Facebook profile:** https://www.facebook.com/benjamin.anderson.121
- **Fandalism profile:** http://fandalism.com/benefactor
- **ReverbNation profile:** http://www.reverbnation.com/musician/benjaminanderson

As it mentions on his profile, he is the singer and songwriter for CODE.

- **CODE Blog:** http://www.reverbnation.com/page_object/page_object_blogs/artist_2894523

December 11, 2013 entry:

> *Recently Easy T (Jun Tatami) and I (Benjamin Anderson under the moniker 'mpi' have been writing lyrics and providing vocals for tracks on the Kill La Kill original soundtrack CD being released on christmas day this year! The tracks are 'Suck your blood' and 'I want to know'. Check them out on release! 最近僕 (Benjamin Anderson)とEasy T (Jun Tatatmi)はキルラキルのアニメのサウンドトラックCDの為にボーカルと歌詞を作ってあげた。 Suck your bloodとI want to knowは ２５日１２月２０１３年　リリース！ 我々の仮名はmpiです！ 皆さんチェックして楽しんで下さい！ 宜しくお願いします！*

Keep in mind that they did not contribute any music, only lyrics and vocals.

You also asked about other vocal work he's done, so here are pages for his main band, CODE:

- **CODE Homepage:** http://code2010est.jimdo.com
- **CODE @ReverbNation:** http://www.reverbnation.com/odeinc

And here are his personal pages at other sites, using various aliases:

- **YouTube:** https://www.youtube.com/user/barracudacocacola/videos
- **ReverbNation:** http://www.reverbnation.com/steviebarracuda
- **SoundCloud:** https://soundcloud.com/dj-phoney

He also did keyboards for a group called "Split Works" in 2006:

http://www.discogs.com/Split-Works-Wide-Open/release/4735590

Additionally, you can find all the comments he's made on YouTube videos here:

https://plus.google.com/104914344750776651199/posts

In *Kill la Kill*, he was the singer for "I want to know", and he provided vocals for "Suck your blood" along with Jun Tatami. The comments shown in the above link make it clear which vocals are his: the segment of "Suck your blood" which played during episode 10 (starting at 21:37) was entirely sung by Jun Tatami.

---

On a side note, I should point out that "Jun Tatami" (the bassist and backup vocalist for CODE) is not the name listed on the credits as the second vocalist for "Suck your blood". Instead, the infamously anonymous vocalist "mpi" was listed.

Taking that into consideration, and comparing Jun Tatami's voice to mpi's, it's clear that they're the same person.

This is the vocalist for "Call your name" and "The Reluctant Heroes" from *Attack on Titan*, and "friends" and "Hill Of Sorrow" from *Guilty Crown*.

---

I hope that's enough information for you to be able to keep enjoying the vocals of Benjamin Anderson. His YouTube channel in particular seems to have quite a lot of music on it.